# Dynamically execute method on std class php

Tags: php, class, methods

```
Class::method()->method();
```

How to execute third method on object if variable meets condition? I need to have this in shorter version:

```
if($a == $b) {
        Class::method()->method()->disabled();
    } else {
        Class::method()->method();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really shorter, but maybe easier to read:

```
$c = Class::method()->method();

if($a == $b) {
    $c->disabled();
}
```

(and you don't have to repeat the `Class::method()->method()` twice)

Comment: well i was wondering maybe there is something like this: Class::method()->method()(if($a == $b) { ->disable() });

Comment: I think it's not easy to read. One weird method: what about `Class::method()->method()->disableIf($a == $b);`?